# What loss function does the 'multinomial' distribution with the gbm package in R use?

Tags: r, gbm, multiclass-classification

All distributions in the `gbm` package in R are associated with a loss function. For example, when we set `distribution = 'binomial'`, the loss function chosen internally is the logistic loss function. Can anyone explain how multi-class classification works with `gbm` and the loss function that is being used for it i.e. when we set `distribution='multinomial'`? Is it using one-vs-all or all-vs-all under the hood for doing its multi-class classification?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the relevant source code. I'm pretty sure it's using cross-entropy for multiclass:

```
    //  GBM by Greg Ridgeway  Copyright (C) 2003

#include "multinomial.h"

CMultinomial::CMultinomial(int cNumClasses, int cRows)
{
   mcNumClasses = cNumClasses;
   mcRows = cRows;

   madProb = new double[cNumClasses * cRows];
}

CMultinomial::~CMultinomial()
{
   if(madProb != NULL)
   {
      delete [] madProb;
   }
}


GBMRESULT CMultinomial::UpdateParams
(
   double *adF,
   double *adOffset,
   double *adWeight,
   unsigned long cLength
)
{
   // Local variables
   unsigned long ii=0;
   unsigned long kk=0;

   // Set the probabilities for each observation in each class
   for (ii = 0; ii < mcRows; ii++)
   {
      double dClassSum = 0.0;
      for (kk = 0; kk < mcNumClasses; kk++)
      {
         int iIdx = ii + kk * mcRows;
         double dF = (adOffset == NULL) ? adF[iIdx] : adF[iIdx] + adOffset[iIdx];
         madProb[iIdx] = adWeight[iIdx] * exp(dF);
         dClassSum += adWeight[iIdx] * exp(dF);
      }

      dClassSum = (dClassSum > 0) ? dClassSum : 1e-8;

      for (kk = 0; kk < mcNumClasses; kk++)
      {
         madProb[ii + kk * mcRows] /= dClassSum;
      }
   }

   return GBM_OK; 
}


GBMRESULT CMultinomial::ComputeWorkingResponse
(
    double *adY,
    double *adMisc,
    double *adOffset,
    double *adF, 
    double *adZ, 
    double *adWeight,
    bool *afInBag,
    unsigned long nTrain,
    int cIdxOff
)
{
    unsigned long i = 0;

    for(i=cIdxOff; i<nTrain+cIdxOff; i++)
    {
       adZ[i] = adY[i] - madProb[i];
    }

    return GBM_OK;
}


GBMRESULT CMultinomial::InitF
(
    double *adY,
    double *adMisc,
    double *adOffset, 
    double *adWeight,
    double &dInitF, 
    unsigned long cLength
)
{
    dInitF = 0.0;
    return GBM_OK;
}

double CMultinomial::Deviance
(
    double *adY,
    double *adMisc,
    double *adOffset, 
    double *adWeight,
    double *adF,
    unsigned long cLength,
    int cIdxOff
)
{
    unsigned long ii=0;
    double dL = 0.0;
    double dW = 0.0;

    for(ii=cIdxOff; ii<cLength+cIdxOff; ii++)
    {
        dL += -adWeight[ii] * adY[ii] * log(madProb[ii]);
        dW += adWeight[ii];
    }

    return dL/dW;
}


GBMRESULT CMultinomial::FitBestConstant
(
    double *adY,
    double *adMisc,
    double *adOffset,
    double *adW,
    double *adF,
    double *adZ,
    unsigned long *aiNodeAssign,
    unsigned long nTrain,
    VEC_P_NODETERMINAL vecpTermNodes,
    unsigned long cTermNodes,
    unsigned long cMinObsInNode,
    bool *afInBag,
    double *adFadj,
   int cIdxOff
)
{
      // Local variables
    GBMRESULT hr = GBM_OK;
    unsigned long iNode = 0;
    unsigned long iObs = 0;

   // Call LocM for the array of values on each node
    for(iNode=0; iNode<cTermNodes; iNode++)
    {
        if(vecpTermNodes[iNode]->cN >= cMinObsInNode)
        {
         // Get the number of nodes here
         double dNum = 0.0;
         double dDenom = 0.0;
         for (iObs = 0; iObs < nTrain; iObs++)
         {
            if(afInBag[iObs] && (aiNodeAssign[iObs] == iNode))
                {
               int iIdx = iObs + cIdxOff;
                    dNum += adW[iIdx] * adZ[iIdx];
               dDenom += adW[iIdx] * fabs(adZ[iIdx]) * (1 - fabs(adZ[iIdx]));
                }
         }

         dDenom = (dDenom > 0) ? dDenom : 1e-8;

         vecpTermNodes[iNode]->dPrediction = dNum / dDenom;
        }
    }

    return hr;
}

double CMultinomial::BagImprovement
(
    double *adY,
    double *adMisc,
    double *adOffset,
    double *adWeight,
    double *adF,
    double *adFadj,
    bool *afInBag,
    double dStepSize,
    unsigned long nTrain
)
{
    double dReturnValue = 0.0;
    double dW = 0.0;

   unsigned long ii;
   unsigned long kk;

   // Calculate the probabilities after the step
   double *adStepProb = new double[mcNumClasses * mcRows];

   // Assume that this is last class - calculate new prob as in updateParams but
   // using (F_ik + ss*Fadj_ik) instead of F_ik. Then calculate OOB improve
   for (ii = 0; ii < mcRows; ii++)
   {
      double dClassSum = 0.0;
      for (kk = 0; kk < mcNumClasses; kk++)
      {
         int iIdx = ii + kk * mcRows;
         double dF = (adOffset == NULL) ? adF[iIdx] : adF[iIdx] + adOffset[iIdx];
         dF += dStepSize * adFadj[iIdx];
         adStepProb[iIdx] = adWeight[iIdx] * exp(dF);
         dClassSum += adWeight[iIdx] * exp(dF);
      }

      dClassSum = (dClassSum > 0) ? dClassSum : 1e-8;

      for (kk = 0; kk < mcNumClasses; kk++)
      {
         adStepProb[ii + kk * mcRows] /= dClassSum;
      }
   }

   // Calculate the improvement
    for(ii=0; ii<nTrain; ii++)
    {
        if(!afInBag[ii])
      {
         for (kk = 0; kk < mcNumClasses; kk++)
         {
            int iIdx = ii + kk * mcRows;
                dReturnValue += adWeight[iIdx] * adY[iIdx] * 
                               (log(adStepProb[iIdx]) - log(madProb[iIdx]));

            dW += adWeight[iIdx] * adY[iIdx];
         }
      }
    }

    return dReturnValue/dW;
}
```

Comment: This question does not ask for any form of source code. Please consider including only the relevant portion of code (if at all). Also, mathematically, the logistic loss function (or the cross entropy function) is well defined for binary classification (mapping classes to -1 and 1). What is the loss function mathematically for cross-entropy for multinomial case (in mathematical form)? For example, one way to solve multinomial problems is to solve K-1 binary problems (for K classes) which is not really a loss function for the multinomial case.